# How to access property of object inside ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I have a generic ObservableCollection

```
public ObservableCollection<T> _DGModels;
```

and I inserted data into the ObservableCollection

```
public static ObservableCollection<dynamic> GetDGModelFromDatabase()
    {

        return new ObservableCollection<dynamic>
        {
            new Student { FirstName="Tom", LastName="Jones"},
            new Student { FirstName="Dick", LastName="Tracey"},
            new Student { FirstName="Harry", LastName="Hill"},
            new Student { FirstName="Jack" , LastName="Sparrow"},
            new Student { FirstName="Davy" , LastName="Jones"}
        };
    }
```

Each of the inserted data is an instance of a class

```
public class Number : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int firstNumber;
    public int lastNumber;

    public int FirstNumber

    public int LastNumber

    public int PlusNumber


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)

}
```

My question is how do I access property of Number which is FirstName or LastName using Type.GetProperty()?

Comment: What is GetProperty()?

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of the Property `FirstName` (or `LastName`) using Reflection, you just need to use the `GetProperty()` as you asked, like this:

```
Number num = new Number() { FirstNumber = 1, LastNumber = 5 };

int first = (int)num.GetType().GetProperty("FirstNumber").GetValue(num,null);

Console.WriteLine(first);
```

Assuming that you `Number` class looks like this:

```
public class Number : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int FirstNumber { get; set; }
    public int LastNumber { get; set; }
    public int PlusNumber { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    { 
        //... 
    }
}
```